# appending content decorated as html elements doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one div container which will be visible only on printing. This div on certain user action should be injected with some content and then sent to print.

```
@media print {
    html body * {
        display: none;
    }

    #toPrint{
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen {
    #toPrint {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

inside Layout page I have following structure

```
<html>
   <body>
      @RenderBody()
      <div id="toPrint"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

and inside view page under dom.ready I have script

```
var content = $("<table />").append(
     $("<tr />").append(
        $("<td />").append("TEST")
      ));
$("#toPrint").append(content);
```

appending with this 'complex element' doesn't work, but with following code works

```
var content = "abc";
$("#toPrint").append(content);
```

I tried to decorate elements with single quotes, tried to inject div instead of table, nothing helper, works just plain string without decorated elements.

Answer (score 0):

Where is div id="toAppend" in your code?

Have you try console.log(content) ?

Comment: I have few reputation to COMMENT initial question, so I can create only answers :(

Comment: Duly noted. I removed my downvote, to help you get up there to commenting status. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var content = $("<table />").append(
     $("<tr />").append(
        $("<td />").append("TEST")
      ));
$("#toPrint").append(content);
```

```css
@media print {
    html body * {
        display: none;
    }

    #toPrint{
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen {
    #toPrint {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='toPrint'>

</div>
```

What you've posted works just as you are wanting it to work, so I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you based on the available information.  I assume simplifying the problem resolved whatever issue you were having.  Just run the above snippet to see that the `TEST` is indeed hidden.